# nodejs run command and print complete message to console

Tags: node.js

I coded a js script to update specified dependencies in package.json. something like this:

```
// find dependencies
const dependencies = ['a', 'b', ...]
dependencies.forEach(item => {
    console.log(`yarn add ${item}`);
    execSync(`yarn add ${item}`);
});
```

output in one loop:

```
> node update-dep.js
yarn add a
warning " > a@x.x.x" has unmet peer dependency "aaa@x.x.x".
warning " > a@x.x.x" has unmet peer dependency "bbb@x.x.x".
```

but If i run the `yarn add a` directly in terminal, the output is:

```
> yarn add a
yarn add v1.22.19

[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > a@x.x.x" has unmet peer dependency "aaa@x.x.x".
warning " > a@x.x.x" has unmet peer dependency "bbb@x.x.x".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ a@x.x.x
info All dependencies
└─ @ax.x.x
✨  Done in 2.04s.
```

This looks like a lot of output information is missing, can I print then completely?

Comment: `yarn` is probably detecting whether it's printing to a terminal or not